# After git merge, This branch is 1 commit behind

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

When doing a git merge (a clean one, no conflict whatsoever), the content of both branches are exactly the same.

However GitHub says "This branch is 1 commit behind...". Looking at the logs, indeed one of them has "merge pull request..." with no file changes.

I tried to do another merge, so that they can be even, but then the OTHER branch became one commit behind, for the same reason...

This happened with git command line and with GitHub Desktop.

When merging with Tower, no issues, it merges without creating those empty commits, and therefore both branches are even.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4):

For merging the following procedure i feel is better ,

Lets say we have a develop branch and a feature branch that needs to be merged into develop

The feature branch was created based of off develop.
Now at the end of your feature related work do a ,

```
git pull --rebase origin develop
```

This makes sure that any new changes in develop are updated in your local feature branch.

Next checkout the develop branch and go another,
    git pull --rebase origin develop

This will make sure that your local develop branch is updated with all recent changes in the parent develop branch.

Now while staying on the develop branch issue the following command,

```
git merge <feature branch name>
```

When merge is successful push out the local develop branch to the remote

```
git push origin develop
```

This will make sure all commits are taken care of.